# How do I install JDK for Java 1.6 SE on OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks

Tags: java, macos

I currently have Java 7 on my machine, but would like to downgrade as some unit tests in my current project fails with newer versions of Java.

**Note that I am running OS X 10.9.1, and the Java installation practices have changed since previous versions of the OS.**

Since Apple has changed the distribution around the time of 1.6, it's not obvious to me how I get the old version. Oracle does not supply Mac packages of 1.6 :(

Clues?

Comment: :) Typo on OS version

Comment: Sami you may want phrase that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The OS/X Mavericks ships with Java 1.6, but in case you've installed another version, you can get back with 1.6 if you download a [bundle of Java SE 1.6.0_65 from Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US).

If you've installed a later version of Java, e.g. 1.7, for all users, installing the bundle mentioned above will most likely break your existing newer installation.

Comment: It does not appear to break a 1.7 install. Also update your .profile like so: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6) change to 1.7 for using version 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

The response here from Sami Laine didn't help me but this StackOverflow page did:
[Java 6 Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394456/java-6-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/31394534#31394534)

To step down from Java 1.8 to 1.6 to support a legacy codebase, I also had to step down Maven from 3.3 to 3.2.